# Component instantiation error

Tags: vhdl

For the following VHDL code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity dff is
  port(
      d, clk: in std_logic;
      q: out std_logic);
end dff;
architecture behave of dff is
  begin
    process(clk)
      begin
      if(clk = '1') then
        q<= d;
    end if;
  end process;
end behave;
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

and and a testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity dff is
end dff;
architecture behave of dff is
  component dff is
port(d, clk: in std_logic;
     q: out std_logic);


 end component;


    signal  d_in: std_logic;
    signal  clk_in: std_logic;
    signal  q_out: std_logic;

begin
  d_ff : dff port map( d_in, clk_in, q_out);
  process
    begin
      if(clk_in = '1') then
      q_out<= d_in;
      end if;
  end process;
end behave;
```

When trying to simulate Modelsim is showing the following error:

> #Error loading design
>   The following component ports are not on the entity:
>                 q
>                 clk
>                 d

Answer (score 4):

The entity name of your testbench is also `dff`. You need to give it a different name (eg `dff_tb`). So, when you compile your testbench, it is overwriting the other `dff` entity.

Comment: A clarification. Overwriting the dff entity (and architecture) isn't an error. The Modelsim error is a semantic check in IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.3.3 Default binding indication, para 9: "The default binding indication includes a default port map aspect if the design entity implied by the entity aspect contains formal ports. The default port map aspect associates each local port in the corresponding component instantiation (if any) with a formal of the same simple name. **It is an error if such a formal does not exist or if its mode and type are not appropriate for such an association.** ...."